# Django uploading SVG files

Tags: django, svg

I am currently using ImageField for uploading images to my site. I discovered today that ImageField does not allow for uploading SVG. The reason being that with SVG files there are potential security issue, SVG files can contain malicious javascript. I could use FileField, but I am wondering if there are ways to use ImageField, or if I use FileField how do I insure that the SVG file is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially write a sanitizer on the file, but it might take a bit of work. Take a look at [Sanitizing SVG](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/archives/001482.html) and maybe the [whitelist in html5lib](https://github.com/clones/html5lib/blob/master/python/src/html5lib/sanitizer.py)

Answer (score 0):

If it's strictly an SVG field, use a validator that tries to parse the SVG content:

```py
import defusedxml.ElementTree as ET
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class SVGFileValidator():
    def __call__(self, value):
        self.validate_file_content(value)

    def validate_file_content(self, value):
        error_message = "Invalid SVG file format."
        try:
            tree = ET.parse(value)
            root = tree.getroot()

            # Check if the root element is an SVG element
            if not root.tag.endswith("svg"):
                raise ValueError(error_message)

        except ET.ParseError:
            raise ValidationError(error_message)
```

Add the validator to the model's field:

```py
image = models.FileField(
    validators=[
        SVGFileValidator(),
    ],
)
```